# Python function for bandwith threshold IndexError: list index out of range Error

Tags: python

I am currently trying to make my Raspberry PI 2 work with Amazon's AWS IoT by following this tutorial: https://www.hackster.io/phantom-formula-e97912/network-monitoring-with-aws-iot-b8b57c?ref=platform&ref_id=425_trending___&offset=12

For this function, that should issue a warning for exceeding a network bandwith threshold:

```
def monspeed():
    c = checkspeed(-1)
    if c[2] > 2000000: # customize the interface/speed to trigger the warning
        awsmsg = {'state':{ 'reported': {'warning': 'speed' , 'result': c}}}
        payload = json.dumps(awsmsg)
        print (awsmsg)
        client.publish(topic,payload,qos,retain)
```

I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "./netmon.py", line 158, in <module> 
monspeed() 
File "./netmon.py", line 98, in monspeed 
if c[2] > 2000000: # customize the interface/speed to trigger the warning 
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please provide a bit more information so that people can help you better. In this case, at least the contents of `checkspeed()` will be necessary. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that `c` object has less than 3 elements in it. That's up to the output of `checkspeed` when it receives -1 as a parameter.

In order to see what happened to `c`, use try/except blocks like this:

```
try:
    if c[2] > 2000000:
        awsmsg = {'state':{ 'reported': {'warning': 'speed' , 'result': c}}}
        payload = json.dumps(awsmsg)
        print (awsmsg)
        client.publish(topic,payload,qos,retain)
except IndexError as e:
    print 'What is "c"?', type(c)
    print 'Values in "c":', c
    raise e
```

Doing this you can check the type and valur of the variable `c` at the moment when the error was triggered.

Using this tactic you can see what happens with variables that might be triggering the error, thus obtaining information useful to find out what is working wrong.